# How can I change the date format for TFS work item query results in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, internationalization, datetime-format

Using VS2010 with TFS and all the date columns in the query results are in US format (ie m/d/yyyy).  Can I change this to the en-AU (Australian) format of d/m/yyyy? Or even the more useful yyyy-mm-dd?

Is there a setting for this or is this format hard-coded into the software.  My OS datetime format settings are set for standard Australian formats

**Update**: should have mentioned, the datetime format in the actual work items is in the correct format, just wrong in the datetime columns in work items query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this, they say you can't

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/teams_wit_tools/faq-4-how-do-you-change-to-format-of-a-date-on-a-work-item)

*"you cannot change appearance of the date/time fields in the results list of a query."*

but that is for TFS 2008.

Since the report is coming from Reporting Services, you might be able to change it on your RS server.

*For Report Designer itself, the SQL Server language resource that is used in the report-authoring environment is determined by the language of the installation of Microsoft Visual Studio. For example, if you are running a Japanese version of Visual Studio, the Japanese language resource for Report Designer is used. If you are using a version of Visual Studio for which there is no close match in the SQL Server languages, the language resource for Report Designer and report definitions is U.S.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493.aspx

Answer (score 15):

In TFS 2015, this is possible.

There's a user profile option accessible at:

http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/Collection/Project/_admin

To change the date/time formatting options, do the following:

---

1. In this top corner, there's a user name; select it, then click My Profile:

   [image: Selecting My Profile]

---

2. From here, the profile page is displayed. Select "LOCALE". Here, there are date and time formatting options, but first the language needs to be changed. The key point is to *not* choose the default browser option:

   [image: User Profile Page]

---

3. Select "English (United States)" *not "Browser: English (United States)", or any other "Browser: xxx" option*

   [image: Selecting English (US)]

---

4. Now, select a date format from the list:

   [image: Selecting a Date Format]

---

5. The same can be done for time:

   [image: Selecting a Time Format]

---

Now, in a modified query that outputs several date fields, it can be seen that the date format is respected (this is from a browser):

[image: Example date output in query respecting new format]